# About the immutableOpenmap in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, immutability, atomic

I would like to ask what consideration is the **immutableOpenmap in Elasticsearch designed for**? What kind of **utility** does it have? It is used in both **aliasmetadata and indexmetadata**. My personal guess is that it has something to do with **atomicity**, but I don't get the full understanding from the code.

Answer (score 1):

From [the source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/collect/ImmutableOpenMap.java#L30)

> An immutable map implementation based on open hash map.

Immutable simply means that once you create it, you cannot modify its content anymore. All [methods that would mutate](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/collect/ImmutableOpenMap.java#L93-L110) the content, whether keys or values, will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.